# Storyboard and CustomCells

Tags: ios, xcode, cells, uistoryboard

I'm new to Objective-C and trying to create custom cells. In the storyboard (under Xcode 4.2) i am pushing a TableViewController. In this Controller i am Displaying some simple Cells, but now i want to customize them. (In older Versions of Xcode, I was using something like this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray * topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (detailViewCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

to load my custom cells, but now that doesn't work anymore because I am getting an error that the Nibfile "MyNib" wasn't found, sure.. because I'm using storyboard.. but how can I fix that? How can I load a CustomCell from Storyboard?

EDIT: "haha, I'm such an idiot.. solved the problem on my own.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"detailsViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

I thought these lines create a new standard cell with the identifier "detailsViewCell", so I haven't changed that to my custom cell identifier yet, but yeah, instead of that they load my created custom cell. :) now everything works well!
"

Comment: No one that knows the answer to this can answer this since iOS 5 is still covered by an NDA. You might be better asking in the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: how do u manage the content? do u have a separate class with iboutlets or can it be managed inside the same uitableviewcontroller class?

Comment: i added new prototype cell to the storyboard (with a custom class) and  a identifier.. and with the above code (in the edit) you can load this cell :) sorry for the late answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to create from Nib anymore, just call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and will return u the cell you want. But at first, you'll need to create a new class for your custom cell.

Found a introduction video for u, [check this out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_989047&v=fnzkcV_XUw8&src_vid=0AsChJk422c&feature=iv)